# like this - A RenderFlex overflowed by 11 pixels on the bottom

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, error-handling

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http_demo/models/product.dart';

class ProductListRowWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  Product product;
  ProductListRowWidget(this.product);



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return buildProductItemCard(context);
  }

  Widget buildProductItemCard(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Card(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Image.network("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/02/13/42/peace-7043225_960_720.jpg"),
              height: 125.0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
            ),
            Text(product.productName,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 13.0), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text(product.unitPrice.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,color: Colors.grey,),textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

---

Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
**A RenderFlex overflowed by 11 pixels on the bottom.**

The relevant error-causing widget was:
Column Column:file:///C:/Users/musta/AndroidStudioProjects/http_demo/lib/widgets/product_list_row.dart:18:16
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etqlO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Column expands to fill the maximum vertical space. You can fix this behaviour by adding to Column the mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min

```
InkWell(
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Image.network(
                      "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/02/13/42/peace-7043225_960_720.jpg"),
                  height: 125.0,
                  width: MediaQuery
                      .of(context)
                      .size
                      .width / 2,
                ),
                Text(product.productName,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 13.0), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                Text(product.unitPrice.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,color: Colors.grey,),textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
```